# NodeJS: fs.createReadStream sometimes does not read the desired "start" and "end" bytes

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm currently using `fs.createReadStream` to read a certain amount of bytes from a file.

Here is my code

```
const readFile = (file, start, end) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let readStream = fs.createReadStream(file, { start : start, end: start+end })

  readStream.on("error", () => {console.log("Error occured on " + file)})
  readStream.on('data', function(d) {
    console.log(start)
    console.log(start+end)
    console.log(d.byteLength)
    resolve(d)
  });
})
}
```

I set the start to 0. And the end as my desired bytes (e.g: 5000).

this function runs in a loop (let's say this runs 10times)

Here is the output (i logged the sizes i get)

```
start: 0
end: 5000
result: 5001
start: 0
end: 5000
result: 5001
start: 0
end: 5000
result: 5001
start: 0
end: 5000
result: 5001
start: 0
end: 5000
result: 432
start: 0
end: 5000
result: 5001
start: 0
end: 5000
result: 4569
start: 0
end: 5000
result: 432
```

Notice the ones who only read less than 5000.

This only happens when I run this multiple times in a loop of more than 10+ times.

What's the problem here?

**Edit:** As you can see, the parameters are all the same. Even the files are all multiple copies of an original file.

**EDIT 2.0:**
This solved my problem! In order for me to get the desired data, I initialized a buffer and concatenated the chunks from `.on('data')` and finally, resolved on `.on('end')`

Here's the updated function:

```
const readFile = (file, start, end) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let data = Buffer.alloc(0)
  let readStream = fs.createReadStream(file, { start : start, end: start+end })
  readStream.on("error", () => {console.log("Error occured on " + file)})
  readStream.on('data', function(d) {
    data = Buffer.concat([data, d])
  });
  readStream.on("end", function(d) {
    console.log(file)
    console.log(start)
    console.log(start+end)
    console.log(data.byteLength)
    resolve(data)
  })
})
}
```

Huge thanks to tawfik nasser!

Comment: Adding some more information about the function is called will be helpful. You have mentioned it is called 10 times in a loop. Is the loop asynchronous or the parameters same for all the calls?

Comment: The parameters are all the same. The function is called inside a .map that returns a promise. Then I handle them all after using Promise.all(). I'm currently wondering why does it returns only few bytes compared to the other calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ReadStream.
So `.on('data')` it returns `chunk` of data.

Also you are resolving on the first chunk of data.

You should resolve `.on('end')` and not in every time you get chunk of data.

Comment: Thanks for this!! Got it to work! now I understand how Readstream work. At first I thought the ```.on('data'``` gives the whole data. So it's only a chunk of data. Accepted your answer! Also edited the question how i got it to work.